# Print Bibliography with Biblatex: Remove Initials and Conjunction "and" Between Authors

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber, bibliographystyle

I use `biblatex`+`biber` with some custom orderings. In particular, I desire a very abbreviated bibliography style for my current document as it's very page limited---a grant proposal, basically.
I have been able to set up the fields that I want and in the order that I want. But I don't know how to do two things.

1. Remove initials: Instead of `Anonymous Person` being displayed as `A. Person`, I would like it to be simply `Person`.
2. Remove the `and` conjunction. I'd like `Smith and Thomas` to be `Smith, Thomas`.

I am using `giveninits=true` as an optional argument which causes `Anonymous` to be reduced to `A.`. I'm guessing that some adjustment to this is required to solve `1.`.
An extremely hacky `\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{}` removes the initials, *however* it does replace them with a single whitespace. I guess I can probably remove one piece of whitespace with further hacking. This doesn't seem like the correct way to solve `2.`, though.

I have looked on SE and through our friend [the biblatex documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), but to no avail. It seems like something like

```
\renewbibmacro{author}{%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
}
```

should work. But it doesn't not. I get "Error: Bibliography macro '\isdot' undefined" and no names are printed.

---

I include as *minimal* a MWE as I dare---I don't want to risk removing more custom commands which may be having an effect.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
    hyperref=auto,
    sorting=nyt,
    maxnames=10,
    maxcitenames=4,
    backend=biber,
    texencoding=auto,
    giveninits=true,
    block=space,
    style = numeric,
    %   style = alphabetic,
    %   style = authoryear-comp,
    %   citestyle = authoryear-comp
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}    % works on biblatex 3.7
%\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}     % doesn't work on 3.7

\DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{{#1\isdot}}

\DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished, online]
    {date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
    {volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
%   [article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
    {pages}{\mkbibparens{#1}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{foo.bib}
    @article{paper,
        author  = {Me, Andrew and Myself, Bethany and I, Charlie},
        title   = {BREAKTHROUGH MATHS},
        year    = {2025}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}



\begin{document}

Citation: \cite{paper}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the initials (for standard styles):

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}
```

To remove "and" between authors:

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

**A better solution, thanks to @moewe (see comments below):**

```
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%thanks to @moewe
%\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}  
\nocite{*}
  \printbibliography[title=Collections,type=collection]
  \printbibliography[title=Books,type=book]
  \printbibliography[title=Articles,type=article]
  \printbibliography[title=Articles,type=article]
  \printbibliography[title=Incollections,type=incollection]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ivan, you've sorted me out again! Thanks `:)`

Comment: Instead of `\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}` I'd prefer `\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}`, because that makes for a more consistent look if I later want to change `multinamedelim`.

Comment: `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}` will add given name initials or full given names if family names alone are not unique and thus ambiguous, which I consider a good idea, but that might not be desired. In that case disabling the `uniquename` feature or defining a real name format that only prints the family name would be the way to go.

Comment: @moewe Can I modify the answer taking into account your comment about `finalnamedelim`? it's definitely a better solution than mine.

Comment: You certainly can, Ivan. Just drop a note at the end of your proof to acknowledge improvement due to moewe.

Comment: Thanks @moewe for the suggestion. In this case I'd be happy with just printing out the ambiguous name. Would adding `uniquenames = false` to the `biblatex` load sort this? I'd also be happy to define such a name format, but I do not know how to do this... :/ -- I tried `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family}` but this made a mess! Also, `\DeclareDelimAlias` gives an `Undefined control sequence` error...

Comment: Also, @Ivan, I am sorry for being presumptuous with the accept: your solution does not remove the initials for me. Adding/removing your first line has no effect. (I am making sure to run `biber` between tries, in case that is needed)

Comment: @SamOT `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}` works in the MWE in Ivan's answer, but it only applies to the 'primary' name at the beginning of the entry. To have the function apply to all names, I'd use `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}`. It is very possible that even that does not quite have the same effect in documents using a different style (that's why it is we always encourage people to post example documents to even the - supposedly - most trivial questions). Please tell what your document looks like at the moment.

Comment: @SamOT If you get an error about an undefined control sequence with `\DeclareDelimAlias` your `biblatex` version is too old. The command was added more than three years ago in version 3.8 of `biblatex`.

Comment: @moewe I use `biblatex3.7` due to the dinosaur that is arXiv. They just recently updated their TeX Live distribution---I think they do so once every 5yrs. I used to use `v3.11`, I think, but downgraded for arXiv compatibility. I shall check to see what they accept now. Regarding removing the initials, I have included as minimal a MWE as I dare. It actually didn't end up being as bad as I thought it might be...

Comment: I've tried a variety of things and upgraded to latest `biblatex`+`biber`. Still can't work out how to print just the surnames... (no initial)

Comment: @SamOT Did you try `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}` as I suggested above? That appears to work in the MWE you posted (I just removed `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}` and added `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}`).

Comment: Ah, no, I didn't... I tried every variation I could think of, using `family`, `given`, `name:family`, etc. I didn't notice that you were suggesting to use _both_, but under `sortname` rather than `default`. In fact, one does not even need the second part: just `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{labelname}` works for me. Caveat: it doesn't only remove initials; it removes prefixes too (eg `L van Beethoven` becomes just `Beethoven`). My data is all in the form `author = {van Beethoven, Ludwig}`. I literally just want to not print the `given` part... :/

Comment: I have added `useprefix = true` to the `biblatex` call. By manually adding `sortname = Beethoven`, this makes sure the ordering is correct. I think this all works...

Comment: @Ivan I have found a bug/unintended consequence of your suggestion. It successfully removes the conjunction from the bibliography. It _also_ does so when I use `\textcite{...}`. This leads to incorrect inline citations, eg "first studied by Smith, Doe [3] in 2021". This is incorrect use of punctuation in a sentence. (The bibliography is not a sentence.) Is there some way of implementing your suggestion for the bibliography without affecting inline citations, eg `\textcite{...}` or `\authorcite{...}`?

Comment: `\DeclareNameAlias[bib]{sortname}{labelname}` and
`\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}`

Comment: Apologies, @Ivan. Somehow I missed your last comment! Thanks for the explanation